# How to read a plain text of digits into array in R

Tags: r, file-io, read.table

For example I have a file containing digits of pi, like this:

```
> 1415926535 8979323846 2643383279 5028841971 6939937510
> 5820974944 5923078164 0628620899 8628034825 3421170679
> 8214808651 3282306647 0938446095 5058223172 5359408128
> 4811174502 8410270193 8521105559 6446229489 5493038196
> 4428810975 6659334461 2847564823 3786783165 2712019091
```

I want to do some statistics on the numbers, but I couldn't figure out how to read all digits into an array

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's identical to a CSV except your separator is a space ' '. So use `read.table/read.csv` with sep= ' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the values into a vector using `scan` like so:

`digits <- scan('digits.txt')`

Or you can read into a `data.frame` using `read.table`:

`digits <- read.table('digits.txt', ' ')`

To get the digits separated, you can first `paste` the groups and then split the resulting sequence:

`digits <- paste(digits, collapse='')`

`digits <- as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(digits), '')[[1]])`

(This assumes the file is named digits.txt and is placed in your working directory.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I found a minor issue that some "0"s are missing for some reason if I use the above provided solution (I checked it with the count function in text editor) while other digits are fine. Any suggestions on how this might have happened?

Comment: @HanXu: I found an error in the code. Not sure if this was the cause. I have updated my answer with the working code.

Trying it right now, it seems to work (OS X 10.9.5 and R 3.1.0). If you are still having problems, let me know some of the details, and I will see if I can help.